# Customised result of sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let me explain you how my table is setup.

I have a table in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CountyCaseUserData] 
(
    [CCId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    [CaseTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [UserInput] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [UserMasterId] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [DepartmentId] [int] NULL,
    [DisplayLabel] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [UniqueEntryRowId] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [UniqueEntryId] [varchar](20) NULL,
)
```

Please check the image for how the data is stored in the table.

[image]

Now I want to get the result like this:

[image]

The column header is `DisplayLabel` and the data is `UserInput`. And I believe it is not just only to transpose data, as header are duplicated.

`UniqueEntryRowId` is unique for each entry combination, and when it change the data is expected to come in other row.

Please ask for any details if required. Thanks

Using this query:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT 
    @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(DisplayLabel)
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT DisplayLabel 
     FROM CountyCaseUserData) AS DisplayLabel

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT UniqueEntryRowId, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM CountyCaseUserData
    PIVOT(max(UserInput) 
          FOR DisplayLabel IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

but it returns:

[image]

Can you please point where I am going wrong here?

Comment: google sql server pivot

Comment: @ZoharPeled please check the edited question

Comment: If you want to do a pivot like that, you need to have a different variable for the select (because it needs to be in an aggregate function). Alternatively, don't use a pivot at all, and just go with `MAX(CASE...`

Comment: Here's an example of how you could do this. `DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery NVARCHAR(MAX), @ColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX), @SelectColumns NVARCHAR(MAX); SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(DisplayLabel), @SelectColumns = ISNULL(@SelectColumns + ',', '') + 'MAX(' + QUOTENAME(DisplayLabel) + ') ' + QUOTENAME(DisplayLabel) FROM CountyCaseUserData GROUP BY DisplayLabel;` then replace `@ColumnName` in your select statement with `@SelectColumns` and add a `GROUP BY UniqueEntryRowId` to the dynamic SQL.

Comment: Why a dynamic pivot? Are `DisplayLabel` choices open-ended and not limited to posted screenshot?

Comment: @Parfait yes the displaylabel choices are not limited. So I am trying with dynamic PIVOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the codes below:

I added row_number() function and partition by DisplayLabel to group the same records and provide a unique row number index

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.DisplayLabel) 
        FROM [dbo].[CountyCaseUserData] c
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')


 set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
 from 
        (
            SELECT UserInput, DisplayLabel,row_number() 
                       over (partition by DisplayLabel order by  CCId) AS No
            from [dbo].[CountyCaseUserData]
       ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(UserInput)
            for DisplayLabel in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p ';


 execute(@query)
```

see the screenshot below:

Sample Data
[image]

Sample Result
[image]